# Invalid regular expression npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

1. i download react wearable from https://github.com/yldio/react-native-wearables-demo#using-android-studios-adb
2. npm install(no error)
3. npm start --reset cache than error - Invalid regular expression: /(.*\**fixtures**\.*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\**tests**\.*)$/: Unterminated character class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zujgV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **npx** and try

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

Comment: my smart watch already connected

Comment: @YeongLestle this may help https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/creating#set-up-watch

Comment: this error came out after npx react-native start --reset-cache
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'scandir',